# Ubuntu 21.04 | Join Office365 Active Directory when installing

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity, active-directory, office365, 21.04

Having read that Ubuntu 21.04 supports joining active directory when installing I quickly downloaded the newest version and gave it a spin.

Sadly it doesn't really work and just freezes the installation gui. As I'm unsure what our active directory domain is, I have tried the ones listed in the office365 admin center:

- companyname.com
- companyname.onmicrosoft.com
  When trying companyname.onmicrosoft.com and clicking on test connection it directly fails with Connection with the domain failed.
  When using companyname.com as domain the GUI completely freezes and after a while I get the message that "Install Ubuntu 21.04" is not responding.

Things that I checked:

- Made sure network is connected (can ping askubuntu.com, etc)
- Searched here for similar issues
- Searched help.ubuntu.com for similar issues
- Tried starting ubiquity via shell to see if any error pop up in the terminal (Nothing there)

Did I stumble apon a bug? Is this intended behaviour? Is there anything I'm doing wrong (most likely)?

Comment: I am new as well for this area. My curiosity prompts me to ask you, Does `realm discover <%AD Domain%>` discovers successfully? What is the DNS IP you gave? As I am learning, Azure has a common DNS IP which is [168.63.129.16](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances). Please keep us posted of your work around in resolving the issue. Appreciate if anyone could help us in this.

Answer (score 0):

The domains you see in the O365 Admin Center are actually Azure Active Directory domains, rather than actual Active Directory domains. Azure AD is managed in the cloud and is separate from Active Directory Domain Services.

If you have a domain-joined workstation, you can find the correct domain name to use by putting this into PowerShell (on Windows 10 1607+, or older if you install a newer version of PowerShell):

```
Get-ComputerInfo -Property CSDomain
```

The installation GUI freezing up definitely sounds like a bug though. I feel like there should be a timeout or something if there's not an acceptable response.